# replace hyphens correct regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is **AusVELS - EAL – Stage A - Reading**

I want to convert it to **AusVELSEALStageAReading**

I have tried the following

```
 assessment = "AusVELS - EAL – Stage A - Reading";
 trimassessment = assessment.replace(/\s/g, '').replace('/\-/g', '');
```

It turns out to be **AusVELS-EAL–StageA-Reading**

can someone tell me the correct regex?

Comment: Your second replacement is a string `'/\-/g'`, not a regex `/\-/g`. Note that you’ll also have to replace the `–` character, which is a U+2013 en dash and not a hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trimasssesment = assessment.replace(/[^\w]/g, '')
```

Comment: `[^\w]` can be written as `\W`.